# Fixing a malformed Partition.(Mac or WIn7)

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

My brother messed with his hard drive partitioning and now can't access his partition.

I've used a SATA-to-USB to connect his hard drive to my mac, Used diskutil list and got the following

```bash
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk3
   1:               Windows_NTFS Untitled                186.8 GB   disk3s1
   2:               Windows_NTFS Untitled                261.3 GB   disk3s5
   3:               Windows_NTFS                         32.2 GB    disk3s6
```

The partition disk3s6 isn't visible, and mounting it doesn't seem to do the job, 
Also in Disk Utility i tried repairing it and got the following

```bash
Verify and Repair volume “disk3s6”
Checking file systemChecking volume.
Checking main boot region.
Main boot region is invalid.  Trying alternate boot region.
Checking alternate boot region.
Alternate boot region is invalid.
The volume  could not be verified completely.
Volume repair complete.Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
Error: Disk Utility can’t repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.
```

I'm really not sure what to do , and usually i would just wipe the entire disk but this partition has 5 extremely important files that must be backed up.

Anyone has an idea what i can do to fix the specific partition on either Mac OS or the Windows machine?

Would be much appreciated .

Thank you
Shai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to show this up for anyone bumping into the same problem,
I've used this free software and was able to fix the problem insanely easy, all i have to say is Phewwwwww ... Stress is over :)

http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/

Answer (score 1):

If you're encountering this problem on a Mac, you are likely running fsck against the device instead of the partition. Instead of running something like:

```
fsck_exfat /dev/disk2
```

... try running this (adjusted for your device/partition):

```
fsck_exfat -y /dev/rdisk2s2
```

The -y option causes fsck_exfat to assume yes as the answer to all questions.  It will attempt to repair all problems that are found.

To determine which mount/partition to use, run:

```
diskutil list
```

You can also trigger this functionality using **Disk Utility**, and running "First Aid" against the drive that won't mount.

Comment: Thank you - but this post is 8 years old :) .